# Using --prod and --release results unstable application Ionic3

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, deployment, apk

Im building an Ionic3.9 application, during the development process, i use the command:

> Ionic cordova build android --device

to run the application on real device, and it works fine.

but at the end of the development process, i tried to produce a release version in order to send an APK to other devices to test the application, i used the following commands:

> Ionic cordova build android --prod --release
>   or:
>   Ionic cordova run android --prod --release

these commands produces .apk file, i tried to install this .apk file in different android devices, but i get an unstable application with very weird behaviorand unexpected results, for example:

1. Input fields are cannot be focused.
2. the tabs navigation won't work.
   .
   .
   .
   .and many other issues.

any help will be appreciated,
thanks.

Comment: Check logs in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurs when i make the build on iMac PC, i tried to do it in Windows PC, and it work like a charm.